# como retornar una cadena en c

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo una funcion para capturar una cadena de caracteres alfanumérica y numérica he visto varias maneras para poder tomar por return la cadena pero no lo consigo

Dejo mi código si alguien pudiera decirme que estoy haciendo mal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gotoxy(int x,int y){
      HANDLE hcon;
      hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
      COORD dwPos;
      dwPos.X = x;
      dwPos.Y= y;
      SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);
}
char*  CaptureString(int Lin_Ini ,int Col_Ini , int Min_Len , int Max_Len , int Format ) {

    int i=0;
    int Len_Captura;
    char captura;
    int prueba;
    char cadena[10];

    if (Format == 1){    
        while(TRUE){
            int i=0;    
            gotoxy(Lin_Ini ,Col_Ini);
            captura = getch();
            sprintf(&cadena[strlen(cadena)] , "%c" , captura);

            if (captura >=48 && captura <=57 || captura == 8 || captura == 13){        
                if (captura == 8){    
                    memset(&cadena[strlen(cadena)], 0x00 , 1);    
                }    
                printf("%s" ,cadena);

                if (captura == 13){    
                    return cadena;    
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    else if (Format == 2 ){    
        while(TRUE){
            int i=0;    
            gotoxy(Lin_Ini ,Col_Ini);
            captura = getch();

            if (captura >=97 && captura <=122 || captura >=48 && captura <=57 || captura == 8){

                sprintf(&cadena[strlen(cadena)] , "%c" , captura);
                printf("%s" ,cadena);

                if (captura == 8){    
                    memset(&cadena[strlen(cadena)], 0x00 , 1);    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char Captura_fin;
    printf("Bienvenido al programa 3 captura de una cadena con formato \n");    
    Captura_fin = CaptureString(12,15,4,12,1);    
    printf("la cadena escrita es ");
    puts (&Captura_fin);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te harías un gran favor a ti mismo si el código lo tabulases correctamente

Comment: Podrias aclarar un poco mas tu problema?? que es lo que no consigues? a cual parte del codigo te refieres?

Comment: gracias al que la edito realmente no se como ponerla bien ajajaja, el tema es que quiero retornar la cadena que estoy almacenando en "cadena" con el sprintf pero cuando la igualo en la parte de abajo a la funcion no me la muestra no se que estoy haciendo mal,

Answer (score 5):

```
char*  CaptureString(int Lin_Ini ,int Col_Ini , int Min_Len , int Max_Len , int Format )
{
  char cadena[10];

  // ...

  return cadena;
}
```

La variable `cadena`, así como está declarada, está haciendo uso de la pila del programa. Al abandonar la función esa reserva se pierde y la variable, simplemente, deja de existir.

Para que la cadena *sobreviva* a la función tiene que estar almacenada en el *heap*, es decir, tienes que usar memoria dinámica:

```
char*  CaptureString(int Lin_Ini ,int Col_Ini , int Min_Len , int Max_Len , int Format )
{
  char* cadena = malloc(10);

  // ...

  return cadena;
}
```

Eso sí, en ese caso no debes olvidar llamar a `free` cuando la variable retornada ya no sea necesaria.

Para evitar este engorro las funciones del estándar suelen recibir las cadenas como referencia. Esto permite a quien consume la función decidir dónde quiere ubicar la variable:

```
void CaptureString(char* cadena, /* ... */)
{
  // ...
}
```

Por cierto, fíjate que no todas las rutas de la función `CaptureString` hacen `return`. eso te puede traer problemas y es una práctica a evitar.